# Update caso o valor não exista

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho essas duas tabelas no banco (SQL Server)

**Tabela Bancos**

```
 ID  CODIGO  NOME                                                     
 1   246     Banco ABC Brasil S.A. 
 2   075     Banco ABN AMRO S.A.   
 3   025     Banco Alfa S.A.       
 4   001     Banco do Brasil S.A.
```

**Tabela Conta**

```
 NRCONTA AGENCIA NRBANCO NOMECOR                                    
 601     1       001     TESTE 1  
 1       1       001     TESTE 2  
 2       2       002     TESTE 3  
 601     1111    001     TESTE 4  
 7       1111    001     TESTE 5  
 27      1       027     TESTE 6  
 27      1       027     TESTE 6
```

Gostaria de atualizar para "***001***" o valor do campo "***NRBANCO***" da tabela ***"Conta"*** caso o valor atual não existir na tabela ***"Bancos"*** campo ***"CODIGO"***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto deve fazer o que você pretende:

```
UPDATE Conta SET NrBanco = '001'
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bancos AS B WHERE B.Codigo = Conta.NrBanco) = 0
```

Como não posso testar, execute primeiro o **SELECT** seguinte para confirmar se ele retorna todas as contas na situação que você definiu.

```
SELECT * FROM Conta AS C
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bancos AS B WHERE B.Codigo = C.NrBanco) = 0
```